# PFFile, PFImageView, DetailController

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, storyboard, detailsview

I am trying to display an image in an UIImageView that i classed as PFImageView in the inspector and connected it to my detail controller.I am pulling the image from my Tableview array and sending it through prepare segue using

```
detailVC.image= [[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"BookImage"];
```

In detail controller i have two properties to help with this

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *BookImage;
@property (retain,nonatomic) PFFile * image;
```

and in the detail controller implementation i call them to display in view did load:

```
    BookImage.file=_image;
    [BookImage loadInBackground];
```

when I run the code though i get this error and my app crashes:

-[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb7bd70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `PFImageView` class may not be getting loaded properly so the incorrect class type is created (`UIImageView`).

As a workaround, add the code:

```
[PFImageView class];
```

somewhere in your app delegate / cell subclass `+ initialize` to force the class to load.

Alternatives would be:

1. `-all_load -ObjC` linker flags
2. Calling any other method on the class anywhere before the cell is loaded from the storyboard / XIB

Comment: Ok i added it to my app delegate m. now the app doesn't crash bu image doesn't show still. i don't know what you meant by initializing it though

Comment: The answer contains a number of alternatives, only 1 is required to force the class to load. Have you debugged to check the file that you're setting exists as expected?

Comment: Ahhhh dude hell yeah i got it to work! Love ya. Problem was i needed to add [self loadinbackground] to link it to my download.